# Resizing my ext4 / partition bet keeps reverting back

Tags: partitioning

[image: gpart taken in installed ubuntu]

this will be my second question on ubuntu, a follow up on my first problem... as i use UBUNTU I am encountering a low disk space reminder, so I decided to extend the partition that is causing low disk space. Booted up a USB that i used to install my UBUNTU, then run gparted. (the above pic is gparted taken on installed UBUNTU not on USB) I resized first the ext4 /home into 100gig after clicking ok, It shows an error that i wont be able to boot. I ignored the error and clicked the arrorw button but error is still there but I proceed. Then next I resize the swap. Adjust it to the right most to give the 60gig for ext4 /. When i click the arrow button it gives an error  and it just revert back to their original sizes. Afraid of losing my files I immediately restart and remove the USB. what could be the problem or is there a mistake on my process? How will I expand ext4 / and resize ext4 /home.

Comment: Did you resize sda8 by moving left side?  should be done from right then moving whole partition to right.  Beware that work on partitions can damage data, backup what you can't lose first.  Make sure all partitions are unmounted.  Do one thing at a time.

Comment: sda8 and sda4 both appear to have extra space that could be allocated to sda6. Depending on how you use Windows vs Ubuntu. Can you make sda4 smaller? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @crip659, I did move sda8 to the right side leaving just a 100gig, clicked ok then the check button. Next is the swap, i did move it all on the right side and again ok  then check button. But it will just go back to its origianl partition..  am I missing something here? Ill do it again later as im using my cellphone now.. thnx for the reply .

Comment: @heynnema i do have a dual boot on my laptop, and i use sda4 to transfer files from ubuntu to windows or vice versa, im not prepared for now in resizing it. sda8 is my first option to resize coz its a part of ubuntu partition already. Ill be recreating the process later as im on my work today.

Comment: Should make sda8 smaller from right side(empty space) first, then move whole smaller partition to right.  Then click on green check mark on top to apply.

Comment: Also you say it gave an error, a screenshot of that error would be helpful.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @crip659 sorry for the late reply, my laptop was taken to my friend's "lab" for dissecting. my windows partition crashed coz i messed up when I tried to recreate and experiment on resizing (my friend tried to salvage my important work files). took 2 days for him to fixed it also. thank you again and my bad. now i learn on my mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The size of sda4 is probably excessive, as you're only using it to transfer files between Windows and Ubuntu. You may wish to resize sda4 at some point.

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of sda8 partition and reduce sda8 by 35G
- **move** sda8 partition all the way right
- **move** sda7 partition all the way right
- **resize** the right side of sda6 partition all the way right
- click the Apply icon